# Laravel Passport API registering new users

Tags: laravel, rest, authentication, laravel-passport

I'm trying to build a login-system for my web-app, but I can't get Passport to work. The app is build as a REST API, so users should be able to register with an email and password, and after this they should be able to login with these credentials (so I think they will need to receive an access token from Passport when the login credentials are correct).

I thought I could just do a JSON post to a 'register' route to register a new user and then do a post to a 'login' route to get the access token back to the client, but there is no such thing as far as I can tell.

How do I register a new user?

Answer (score 0):

If you're building SPA and using default Laravel register, login, forgot password, & reset password web functionality like [Google Account](https://account.google.com) for authentication & authorization purpose, you can override the registered method on `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php` with redirect logic when intended url is exists.

This lines tells Laravel to look over intended url, prior navigation to the web register controller redirect path.

```php
   /**
     * The user has been registered.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
    {
        if ($request->session()->has('url.intended')) {
            return redirect()->intended();
        }
    }
```

For example I'm using authorization code with PKCE grant on my Vue.js SFC

```
<template>
  <v-app-bar app flat>
    <button-login @login="authorize"></button-login>

    <span>|</span>

    <button-register @register="authorize"></button-register>
  </v-app-bar>
</template>

<script>
import ButtonLogin from '@/components/Buttons/ButtonLogin'
import ButtonRegister from '@/components/Buttons/ButtonRegister'
import { base64URL, encrypt, hashMake, randomString } from '@/helpers'
import sha256 from 'crypto-js/sha256'
import httpBuildQuery from 'http-build-query'
import { SERVICE } from '@/config/services'
import { STORAGE_API_AUTHORIZATION_STATE, STORAGE_API_CODE_VERIFIER } from '@/config/storage'

export default {
  name: 'AppBar',

  components: {
    ButtonLogin,
    ButtonRegister
  },

  authorize() {
      const authorizationState = randomString(40)

      const codeVerifier = randomString(128)

      const codeChallenge = base64URL(sha256(codeVerifier))

      const query = httpBuildQuery({
        client_id: SERVICE.CLIENT_ID,
        redirect_uri: authorizationURL,
        response_type: 'code',
        scope: '*',
        state: authorizationState,
        code_challenge: codeChallenge,
        code_challenge_method: 'S256'
      })

      localStorage.setItem(
        STORAGE_API_AUTHORIZATION_STATE,
        hashMake(authorizationState)
      )

      localStorage.setItem(
        STORAGE_API_CODE_VERIFIER,
        encrypt(codeVerifier, authorizationState)
      )

      location.href = `${SERVICE.API_URL}/oauth/authorize?${query}`
    }
}
</script>
```

Whenever user click on login/register button on my SPA it'll redirect to my API OAuth authorization page.

The authenticate middleware will intercept the request and check for the logged in state of user, if user is not authenticated then it'll redirect user to the login page.

If user choose to register his/her account by clicking on the register button, we will redirect user to the web registration page (still on API not on SPA).

After the user is registered, the controller will call registered method and check for intended URL existence, if exists then we are able to redirect user to the intended url (the `oauth/authorize` endpoint), and the authorization process can be continued after registration process.

Answer (score -2):

I'm facing the same problem here, and by now the best solution I've found is to create the register method manually by creating a UserController and a store method like this

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $data=$request->only('name', 'email','password');
            $valid = validator(
                    $data, [
                'name' => 'required|string|max:255',',
                'email' => 'required|string|email|max:155|unique:users',
                'password' => 'required|string|min:4',
            ]);

            $return=null;
            if ($valid->fails()) {
                $return = response()->json($valid->errors()->all(), 400);

            }else{
                $data['password']=Hash::make($data['password']);
                #return = User::create($data);
            }        
            return $return;
}
```